# UIWebview integration in Cocos2d game?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, cocos2d-iphone

i am developing a small game in which i am **integrating ads in a UIWebview**. Since a UIKit object i am having difficulties in adding it to a Cocos2d layer. its simple enough to add it to one layer but the Webview takes time to load. Meanwhile as i move to some other class the UIWebview loads and gets added to that particular CCLayer class,to remove them in the very same class i use

```
[webViewH stopLoading];
[webViewF stopLoading];

    webViewF.hidden=YES;
webViewH.hidden=YES;

[webViewH removeFromSuperview];
[webViewF removeFromSuperview];
```

but my app gets killed as soon as i move to the other class giving error with NSZombieEnabled -- **Webview:didCommitLoadForFrame or sometimes Webview:didclearwindowObject**. i guess its still loading in the previous class while i have removed it from superview so app gets killed?? what am i possibly doing wrong??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently added a UIWebView to my cocos2d game using a class posted on the cocos2d forum. It's called CCUIViewWrapper and as its name suggests is a CCNode object that wraps any UIView control. Pretty neat.

See more at here:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/tags/ccuiviewwrapper

Answer (score 0):

You can't add UIViews to any Cocos object since they aren't UIViews. Add the UIWebView to the openGLView, which will put the view on top of your game, which is what you wanted:

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubView:webview];`